# mock unit testing file reading and writing in python 2.7

Tags: python, unit-testing, ftp, mocking, filesystems

I am creating a file downloader API in Python. The API will be able to download files from a host using FTP or SFTP (I have implemented separate classes for both) and should also keep track of already downloaded files in the form of a CSV file, database table or Excel file (I have implemented separate classes for all). I have done some basic implementation and now I want to unit test all my methods (because I don't want to actually download files from a real host and save on my machine but just want to make sure it works the way it is supposed to work). I am having hard time finding a good starting point for unit testing, specially to unit test the file handling part and the FTP, SFTP downloader methods. My complete code can be found here 
https://ghostbin.com/paste/o8jxk

Any help or useful learning sources will be appreciated.

The code for file read write class

```
class CSVManager(DownloadManager):

        def __init__(self, file_path, csv_file):
    self.path = os.path.join(file_path, csv_file)

def register_download(self, file_name):
    files = file_name
    with open(self.path, "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for file in files:
            writer.writerow(file)

def downloaded(self):
    downloaded_files = []
    with open(self.path, "rb") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for file in reader:
            downloaded_files.append(file)
    return downloaded_files
```

Comment: Use mock over FTP method and mock method return dummy file name if test file downloaded else None

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to look into [mock](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock) which is part of the standard Python library in Python 3+.  [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html) is particularly useful for mocking out files including reading and writing contents and the Python documentation has a lot of useful examples.

Even though you are using Python 2.7 mock is made to be backwards compatible so you should be able to pip install mock

Answer (score 0):

I tested it using test fixtures https://pythonhosted.org/testfixtures/files.html. Here is my code :

```
def test_CSVManager_register_download_and_downloaded_methods(self):
    with TempDirectory() as d:
        myList = ['test', 'test1', 'test2']
        d.write('test.csv', 'test')
        csvManager = CSVManager(d.path, 'test.csv')
        csvManager.register_download(myList)
        print(csvManager.downloaded())
        print(d.read('test.csv'))
```